# org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory In GlassFish Server while using Bonecp or hikari cp

Tags: java, glassfish, bonecp, hikaricp

I am new to webservices, just I started by writing a simple database function using BoneCP(Connection Pooling) while running the tester wsdl generated by GlassFish Server, I am getting the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:952)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:666)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1220)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1750)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPConfig.<clinit>(BoneCPConfig.java:60)
... 64 more
```

please suggest how to resolve

Answer (score 0):

i know this is an old question but thought to answer this as it might be helpfull to someone else.

I faced the similar issue and i resolved it by doing 2 changes
1.) moved the slf4j jar above the logback-core and logback-classic jars
2.) downloaded new slf4j jar version slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar